# Given 3 points, how to construct an arc that passes through them?

Tags: c#, geometry

Let's say I have 3 consecutive points (`P1`,`P2`, `P3`), how to construct an Arc that passes through all 3 points?

The arc must have the following 3 properties:

1. Start Radian
2. End Radian
3. Center Point

The arc is drawn from `Start Radian` to `End Radian` in counter-clockwise manner.

I've tried with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898089/c-drawing-arc-with-3-points), but it doesn't work, simply because it assumes that `P1` must correspond to `Start Radian` and `P3` must correspond to `end radian`. But the reality is that this is not always valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw two lines between them, following the order you want the arc to take. Bisect both lines, coming up with their normals. The intersection of the normals is the center of the arc. Draw your arc from one endpoint to the other, with the given center.

Comment: `Draw your arc from one endpoint to the other`, actually I'm stuck here. There are two ways where the arc can be drawn, how to draw the arc so that it passes all 3 points, that's the hard part.

Comment: Take the `atan2()` of the three points. You'll know the order you want them to be in since you have the initial two lines; just add 2*pi until they line up.

Comment: @lgnacio, I don't quite understand your comment, would you mind to be more explicit on this?

Comment: The three points are at a certain angle around the center. When you find these angles via `atan2()` they will be in one of 6 orders (123, 231, 312, 321, 132, 213). You need to find the two orders that you care about (probably 123 and 321), and add a full circle to the points that are out of order in order to rearrange them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is a small snippet in C for that. As you can see there are two possible points for the center point. I hope it helps. Credits to my soon Ignacio:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    float x1,y1; //Punto A
    float x2,y2; //Punto B
    float x3,y3; //Punto medio
    float x,y;
    float z,t; //los otros posibles puntos
    float R; //Distancia

    printf("Introduce  Ax:\n");
    scanf ("%f",&x1);
    printf("Introduce  Ay:\n");
    scanf ("%f",&y1);
    printf("Introduce  Bx:\n");
    scanf ("%f",&x2);
    printf("Introduce  By:\n");
    scanf ("%f",&y2);
    printf("Introduce  Cx:\n");
    scanf ("%f",&x3);
    printf("Introduce  Cy:\n");
    scanf ("%f",&y3);
    printf("Introduce la distancia:\n");
    scanf ("%f",&R);


    x=-((-(x2*x2)+2*x1*x2-(x1*x1))*x3-(x3*y1*y1)+(2*x3*y1*y2)-(x3*y2*y2)+(y2-y1)*sqrt(y2*y2-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1)*R)/(y2*y2-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1);
    y=((y2*y2-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1)*y3+(x2-x1)*sqrt(y2*y2-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1)*R)/(y2*y2-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1);
    printf ("x=%f\n",x);
    printf ("y=%f\n",y);

    z=((y2-y1)*sqrt((y2*y2)-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1)*R+x3*y2*y2-2*x3*y1*y2+x3*y1*y1+(x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1)*x3)/(y2*y2-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1);
    t=-((x2-x1)*sqrt(y2*y2-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1)*R+(-(y2*y2)+2*y1*y2-(y1*y1)-(x2*x2)+2*x1*x2-(x1*x1)*y3))/(y2*y2-2*y1*y2+y1*y1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+x1*x1);
    printf ("\nx=%f\n",z);
    printf ("y=%f\n",t);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```