# How to find points along arc if given initial point, ending point, random point + precision?

Tags: math, geometry, point, angle

the precision is the number of points I want for my vector, from 0, the initial point of my arc, to the precision I want minus 1.

Code example in c++:

```
int precision = 20;
double pointInit[3] = {2,5,2};
double pointRandom[3] = {3,7,1};
double pointInit[3] = {0,-3,1};

std::vector<std::array<double,3>> pointArc;  
std::array<double, 3> currentPoint; 

// Fill the pointArc vector, from 0 (initial point) to precision -1 (ending point)
for (int i = 0 ; i < precision; i++)
{
    // Find the value of the current point
    // currentPoint[0] = ????;
    // currentPoint[1] = ????;
    // currentPoint[2] = ????;
    pointArc.push_back(currentPoint);
}
```

EDIT : The arc I'm looking for is a circular arc

Comment: Is it a circular arc?

Comment: Yes it's a circular arc, I forgot to mention it. I will add the edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

Use `atan2()` to find the angles of the endpoints with respect to the center, subtend the angle between them `precision - 1` times, and convert the polar coordinates (use one of the endpoints to get the distance from the center) to rectangular form.

Comment: @asdfasdf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420968/given-3-points-how-to-construct-an-arc-that-passes-through-them

Comment: This seems to be for 2d points, which is a bi simpler than 3d points. For example, I can't find the normal of the lines

Comment: Ah, I missed that this was three-dimensional. In that case the normals will be planes that will meet on a line. The center will be a point on that line.

Answer (score 0):

1) translate the three points so that `P0` comes to the origin

2) consider the vectors `P0P1` and `P0P2` and form an orthonormal basis by the [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) process (this is easy)

3) in this new basis, the coordinates of the three points are `(0, 0, 0)`, `(X1, 0, 0)`, `(X2, Y2, 0)`, and you have turned the 3D problem to 2D. (Actually `X1=d(P0,P1)` and `X2`, `Y2` are obtained from the dot and cross products of `P0P2` with `P0P1 / X1`)

The equation of a 2D circle through the origin is

```
x² + y² = 2Xc.x + 2Yc.y
```

Plugging the above coordinates, you easily solve the 2x2 system for `Xc` and `Yc`.

```
X1² = 2Xc.X1
X2² + Y2² = 2Xc.X2 + 2Yc.Y2
```

4) The parametric equation of the circle is

```
x = Xc + R cos(t)
y = Yc + R sin(t)
```

where `R²=Xc²+Yc²`.

You can find the angles `t0` and `t2` corresponding to the endpoints with `tan(t) = (y - Yc) / (x - Xc)`.

5) interpolate on the angle `t0.(1-i/n) + t2.i/n`, compute the reduced coordinates `x`, `y` from the parametric equation and apply the inverse transforms of 2) and 1).